# How to decrease MATLAB Runtime compiler size to make a stand alone application?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I just want to make an exe file in MATLAb to make a stand-alone application, after some research on the internet I found [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html) on the MATLAB website and download MATLAB Runtime compile and made my application.

It makes me a exe file but the problem is that if you want to run your code on another computer without installing MATLAB Runtime compiler it does not work.

In .Net application we install .Net framework it's OK but in this case MATLAB Runtime compiler has a huge size, it's about 1.7GB and it's little hard for user to download and install it on their computer.

Is there any way to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Matlab Coder](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) to generate C code which you can then compile. It will not do graphics though, but it will do a lot (including some advanced signal processing). There is no way around installing the Matlab Runtime Compiler if you want graphics, although if your application runs on antiquated Matlab 5.3 (about 20 years old), this version of Matlab used to create standalone applications (with graphics) that did not require the runtime compiler.

Comment: You can also check out: [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/223937-should-i-use-matlab-compiler-sdk-or-matlab-coder-to-integrate-my-matlab-applications-with-c-c#answer_182772) which compares and contrasts MATLAB Compiler and MATLAB Coder